# Laravel relation error - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get the id of the relations I have setup.

**Plate** model

```
public function plateContainer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\PlateContainer');
}
```

**PlateContainer** Model

```
public function plate()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Plate');
}

public function equipmentStatusCode()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\EquipmentStatusCode');
}
```

**EquipmentStatusCode** Model

```
public function plateContainer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\PlateContainer');
}
```

When I try.

```
    $p  = Plate::findOrFail(4);
    $p->plateContainer->equipmentStatusCode;

  return $p;
```

I get `Trying to get property of non-object`. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `plateContainer` isn't a property of `$p` but a method. That's why you get the error.

Comment: @Daan How I might go solving this?

Comment: specify the table structure for tables `plates` and `equipment_status_codes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

I just tried to create a similar situation. I modified the code likewise:

```
$p  = Plate::findOrFail(4);

$p->equipmentStatusCode->plateContainer;
return $p;
```

I was able to fetch the result array.

Comment: It is my fault. This one worked getting the very first error was because I had nothing in my DB ( I know it's stupid). Thanks everyone for the effort!

Comment: Happy that you found the solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

`plateContainer` and `equipmentStatusCode` are a functions. Use rounded brackets.

Add the following relation to the Plate model:

```
public function equipmentStatusCode()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\EquipmentStatusCode', 'App\Models\PlateContainer');
}
```

And try:

```
$p  = Plate::findOrFail(4);
$p->equipmentStatusCode();

return $p;
```

Comment: I have tried this already. I am getting `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$equipmentStatusCode`

Comment: You have to add rounded brackets after equipmentStatusCode. I edited my asnwer.

Comment: I gave your updated code a try, Now I get `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::equipmentStatusCode()`

Comment: Oh yes, you have to use hasManyThrough relation. Please try it!